# React Native- Type Script : What is the way to set the time 7am when the button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

What is the way to set the time 7am when the button `returnToDefault` is pressed?

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';


const Preferences = () => {
const [openHours, setOpenHours] = useState(false);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(new Date());

return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => setOpenHours(true)}
            >
              <Text>
                {moment(hours).format('LTS')}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
<DatePicker
              modal
              mode='time'
              open={openHours}
              date={hours}
              onConfirm={orderDate => {
                setOpenHours(false);
                setHours(new Date(orderDate));
              }}
              onCancel={() => {
                setOpenHours(false);
              }}
            />

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={returnToDefault}
        >
          <Text>return to default</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const returnToDefault=()=>{
   setHours(moment()
    .set('hours', 7)
    .set('minutes', 0)
    .set('seconds', 0)
    .set('milliseconds', 0)
    .toDate());
}
```

And, in TouchableOpacity,

```
   {moment(hours).format('hh:mm')}
```

instead of

{moment(hours).format('LTS')}

Comment: but its give me " 7:00:00 AM " and i just want 07:00

Comment: something there not correct its gives an error..
"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.ts(2345)"

Comment: hours was of type Date. It should be fixed now. Please check the answer once, is edited again